# How to deactivate the flow using workbench API

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-communities, salesforce-flow

How to deactivate/delete flow through WorkBench API or Apex? I tried all possible ways. could anyone help out here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Workbench feature and then deactivate flow through metadata when a process is installed using a managed package and that process references a custom object that isn't in the target org. In this case, the process is active and can't be edited using the Process Builder.
Resolution
Follow these steps to deactivate a process.

1. Log into Workbench. Read more here about Workbench.
2. Use Workbench to retrieve metadata components and then download those components in a .zip file.
   Read about Metadata for more information.
3. Modify the flow definition file (contained in the .zip file you downloaded) by specifying a value of 0 in active version number.
   Note that the flow definition file is available only in API version 34 and later.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338777&type=1

use the above link